# IBM ESQL dynamically access to fields

Tags: xml, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

i need to access to a field using variable,

1. i have the enviroment variable containing the path of the field i
   need to modify es. **SET
   Environment.Variabili.Mappings.mapping[1].xpath='trades.trade[1].id';**
2. i want to modify the value of this field usinng the enviroment
   variable es.SET
   OutputRoot.XML.MxML.{Environment.Variabili.Mappings.mapping[1].xpath}='test';

But it does not modify the field but it create an other field like this:

```
<MxML>
  ...
  ...
  ...
  <trades.trade[1].id>test</trades.trade[1].id>
<MxML>
```

Is it possible to dynamically acces to the XML field?

Ty.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accidentally using the XML domain. Your statement should be
`SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.MxML...`

Your ESQL SET statement is behaving according to the specification. It has created a new tag with the name taken from the value of `Environment.Variabili.Mappings.mapping[1].xpath`

If you want to dynamically create subfields within the output tree then you will need to 
- write some ESQL to tokenize the value of `Environment.Variabili.Mappings.mapping[1].xpath`
- use the CREATE statement to create each field in the output tree.

Before you go ahead and write that code, you may want to consider a change of design. It would be easier to create the tree structure in the Environment tree and just copy it into OutputRoot.XMLNSC.